# Spring Boot remote configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to know if anyone has any experience or suggestions for configuring Spring Boot using remote properties (e.g., properties located in a database on a remote machine instead of an `application.properties` file).  I am aware of Spring Boot's external config options, but these all assume configuration is done through a `.properties` file.

Ideally I would only have to hard-code the configuration for a single datasource, and then all subsequent configurations for the various `@Beans` could be done with remotely-fetched values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spring Cloud](http://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) has a bootstrap `ApplicationContext` that you can customize and use to add properties to the `Environment`. The `spring-cloud-config-client` is pretty lightweight and has no mandatory dependencies other than Spring. Documentation is [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_customizing_the_bootstrap_configuration). Example bootstrap configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomPropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {
        return new MapPropertySource("databaseProperties",
                getPropertiesFromDatabase());
    }

}
```

Implementation of `getPropertiesFromDatabase()` is up to you.