# how to refer to config file on remote server in @PropertySource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a Configuration class whose members are to be set as read from a property file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("how to specify file on remote server")
public class DbConfiguration {

    @Value("${hic.db.machine}")
    private String machine;
}
```

I tried `sftp://10.6.X.XX/path/to/file` but it said file not found
I tried `file://10.6.X.XX/path/to/file` but it said connection refused.

Any idea how can i achieve this.

Comment: This is not possible. At least not that easy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118902/spring-boot-remote-configuration

Comment: Ok, I thought there will be a way cuz when i tried with file:// it gave me connection refused.